# Return table (id, STR3) where id is from one table, STR3 from another and tables have the same string in field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

```
t1(ID int, STR1 varchar(20), STR2 varchar(30)),
t2(STR1ID varchar(20), STR3 varchar(30)),
t3(STR1ID varchar(20), STR3 varchar(30)).
```

How can I write a request that will return a table `(ID int, STR3 varchar(30))` where for each string from `t1` will be written `STR3` of string from `t2`, in which `STR1ID == STR1`. If there is no such string in `t2`, request should try to find such string in `t3` and, if there is no such string in `t3`, don't add this string in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need left joins of `t1` to the other 2 tables:

```
select 
  t1.id,
  coalesce(t2.str3, t3.str3) str3
from t1 
left join t2 on t2.str1id = t1.str1
left join t3 on t3.str1id = t1.str1
```